# DirectX: Small distortion between 2 sprite polygons

Tags: c++, directx, sprite, shader, vertex-buffer

Hello I use the same way to render sprites with directx from a long time but here I am rendering the screen in a texture and then render it with a big sprite on the screen.

For the camera I use that:
    vUpVec=D3DXVECTOR3(0,1,0);
    vLookatPt=D3DXVECTOR3(0,0,0);
    vFromPt=D3DXVECTOR3(0,0,-1);

```
D3DXMatrixLookAtRH( &matView, &vFromPt, &vLookatPt, &vUpVec );
g_pd3dDevice->SetTransform( D3DTS_VIEW, &matView );

D3DXMatrixOrthoRH( &matProj, 1,1, 0.5f, 20 );
g_pd3dDevice->SetTransform( D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProj );
```

And to render the sprite:
        CUSTOMVERTEX* v;
    spritevb->Lock( 0, 0, (void**)&v, 0 );

```
v[0].position = D3DXVECTOR3(-0.5f,-0.5f,0); v[0].u=0; v[0].v=1;
v[1].position = D3DXVECTOR3(-0.5f,0.5f,0); v[1].u=0; v[1].v=0;
v[2].position = D3DXVECTOR3(0.5f,-0.5f,0); v[2].u=1; v[2].v=1;
v[3].position = D3DXVECTOR3(0.5f,0.5f,0); v[3].u=1; v[3].v=0;

spritevb->Unlock();


g_pd3dDevice->DrawPrimitive( D3DPT_TRIANGLESTRIP, 0, 2 );
```

This is very basic and works, my sprite is rendered on the screen full.
But by looking closer I see that there's a small diagonal line through the screen (between the 2 polygons) not a colored one but like if them weren't perfectly positionned.

I thought about filtering and tried removing everything  but maybe I forget something...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render to full screen best way is to not define any camera positions.

If you use as input positions

```
SimpleVertex vertices[] =
    {
        { XMFLOAT3( -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f ), XMFLOAT2( 0.0f, 0.0f ) },
        { XMFLOAT3( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f ), XMFLOAT2( 1.0f, 0.0f ) },
        { XMFLOAT3( 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.5f ), XMFLOAT2( 1.0f, 1.0f ) },
        { XMFLOAT3( -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.5f ), XMFLOAT2( 0.0f, 1.0f ) },
    };
```

and in the Vertex Shader do

```
VS_OUTPUT RenderSceneVS( VS_INPUT input )
{
    VS_OUTPUT Output;

    Output.Position = input.Position;

    Output.TextureUV = input.TextureUV; 

    return Output;    
}
```

you get a render to full screen as well without having to worry about the viewing frustrum. Using this I never saw any lines between the two triangles.

Comment: It's really a better way to do but the line is still there, you can see the problem in that [link](http://www.logoetplus.fr/testipn/test.gif) and you'll see there's also some vertical and horizontal lines which can let thinking the texture doesn't fit exactly the backbuffer...

Comment: After writting my comment I tried to add 1 pixel in the height and width of the texture and it removed the lines...

Comment: Not to use a different size I don't just remove half a pixel in sprite size which is the same, it work well, thanks for your help.